# Facebook says my link is insecure including the image link

Tags: wordpress, facebook

Facebook is giving me a warning message every time I try to share any link from my blog, jazminemedia.

It gives me this message:

> wp-content and wp-content/upload are both insecure

I don't understand what's wrong. I tried using Facebook debug and it says:

> the following properties are specified on the webpage but NOT supported for the specified 'og:type': article:publisher, article:tag, article:section, article:published_time

and

> The following required properties are missing: fb:app_id

This is a problem that began suddenly; I used to share on Facebook normally. I tried to disable open graph meta tag but its still not working.

Comment: the fb:app_ID tag in the header of your site is missing or not specified. That's the facebook ID of your application. If you don't have it specified, it's not going to work.

Comment: i tried to add the app id on Yoast SEO, but kept the open graph meta tag disabled, i purged the cashe and tried debug again for the links and tried to post them, it still says this message when i try to share on fb: it looks like this link is insecure 'insert my blog link'/wp-content and 'insert my blog link'/wp-content/upload

Comment: @JonathanLaliberte  facebook ID is not needed if `og:type` is "website"
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/faqs#faq_585424284973304

Comment: @NariKim could you parse the url in the Sharing Debugger and post output here: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing I'm also having this issue